# Trocar a cor de uma lista de acordo com uma determinada variavel

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-adapter

Estou tentando fazer com que a minha lista de cronogramas tenha cada linha com cores diferentes para cada categoria que fora definida, essa lista é preenchida por dados recuperados do firebase que vão para a classe modelo, queria que quando esse DialogFragment fosse chamado para listar o cronograma ele diferenciasse cada categoria por cor(espiritual azul, gincana amarelo, lazer verde), segue o código do meu adapter aonde tento alterar a cor de cada uma das linhas:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    //Validando e criando a lista
    if (arrayList != null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Montando a view a partir do XML
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_cronograma, parent, false);

        //Recuperando os elementos para exibição
        TextView inicio = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hora_inicio);
        TextView fim = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_hora_fim);
        TextView atividade = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_atividade);

        Cronograma crono =  arrayList.get(position);
        inicio.setText(crono.getHoraInicio());
        fim.setText(crono.getHoraFim());
        atividade.setText(crono.getAtividade());

        switch (crono.getCategoria()){
            case "Espiritual":
                inicio.setBackgroundColor(0xCFD8DC);
                fim.setBackgroundColor(0xCFD8DC);
                atividade.setBackgroundColor(0xCFD8DC);
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xCFD8DC);
                break;
            case "Gincana":
                inicio.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF9C4);
                fim.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF9C4);
                atividade.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF9C4);
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFF9C4);
                break;
            case "Lazer":
                inicio.setBackgroundColor(0xDCEDC8);
                fim.setBackgroundColor(0xDCEDC8);
                atividade.setBackgroundColor(0xDCEDC8);
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xDCEDC8);
                break;
        }

    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema com o código?

Answer (score 0):

Recupere também o seu layout container de `lista_cronograma`.
Algo como:

```
ConstraintLayout rootCL = (ConstraintLayout) listItem.findViewById(R.id.root_cl);
```

E onde precisar, altere a cor de fundo normalmente:

```
rootCL.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

faça uma referencia ao seu elemento root de layout:

```
LinearLayout linearRoot = view.findViewById(R.id.linearRoot);
```

Agora será possível ter controle sobre suas propriedades:

```
linearRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

ou...

```
linearRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff00"));
```